# Magento - Mage::registry inside view

Tags: magento

I have a scenario where I need to get the current category name in the layered nav.  Obvisouly this views block doesnt have access to the current category name and so I am left with a couple of options the easiest being to use Mage::register('current_category') inside the view but this is jarring with me and I know it shouldnt be in there.

The other options seem so over the top for such a simple thing (create an override, create a separate module) that I am considering keeping the register access call inside the view.

Just need some opinions from more experienced magento developers out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is accessing the variable with `Mage::registry`, I think that is safe enough.  If you were getting a collection, filtering and manipulating values, then you should consider creating your own Block.

The rationale is (IMHO) - anything that would benefit from being cached should be in a Block.  Outputting values is fine in a View.

HTH,
JD